# URL Behaviour in a Visual Studio Web Reference

Tags: visual-studio, web-reference

Please can some one explain exactly what the URL Behaviour (Static or Dynamic) property for a Web Reference in Visual Studio is for.

I believe it affects where the URl for the Web Service is stored but I don't have a clear understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I believe it affects where the URl for
>   the Web Service is stored but I don't
>   have a clear understanding.

That's right.

If you set it to dynamic, afterwards you can change url of web service (WebService.Url). [Details here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx).

Answer (score 26):

Here's a bit more complete answer.

**Dynamic** automatically adds a setting that specifies Web Service URL. Yes, it can be managed through `app.config`, but the setting must reside in a specific place of `app.config` under `<applicationSettings>`.

**Static** makes the proxy's constructor to initialize `Url` property to its original value.

So if you have your own URL handling (e.g. the URL is retrieved from the database or resides in another section of `app.config`), `URL Behaviour` must be `Static` and changed later in your custom code.

Comment: A bit more complete indeed. +1